# i am building a django projects using a medium blogpost, i cannot understand the purpose of these three lines of code

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

this application is a order manager and I am new to django therefore
i do not know what these line of code do so please help me understand what this piece of code is used for

```
objects = models.Manager()
browser = ProductManager()
tag_final_value.short_description = 'Value'
```

this my models.py file

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    value = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    discount_value = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    final_value = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    qty = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    objects = models.Manager()
    browser = ProductManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Products'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.final_value = self.discount_value if self.discount_value > 0 else self.value
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def tag_final_value(self):
        return f'{CURRENCY} {self.final_value}'
    tag_final_value.short_description = 'Value'
```

this my managers.py file

```
from django.db import models


class ProductManager(models.Manager):

    def active(self):
        return self.filter(active=True)

    def have_qty(self):
        return self.active().filter(qty__gte=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objects` is your `default manager`
You can get all objects on particular model by using
`products = Products.objects.all()`
`browser` is your custom model you have created by using a class ProductManager. 
You can get all objects using this manager by using
`products = Products.browser.all()`

Basically, by defining a custom manager you can narrow down your queryset with some methods you would like to add. So, that you don't have to user filters and other complex queryset all the time you can just call your custom manager

You can read more [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#managers)